# log4j:ERROR with Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, tomcat6

I programmed a Web Application with Java EE. I am using log4j and Tomcat 6.0.28. When I am starting my app at tomcat following error message appears every 3 seconds at my console:

```
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
```

Has somebody an idea what that means? Is there maybe a problem with log4j.xml? I can post more code/configfiles if nessecary.

The application works, but I am a little bit worried.
Thank you...

Comment: I don't know if this will help: http://marc.info/?l=log4j-user&m=120897082320333

Comment: Exactly what solved this issue? Did you try adding the parameter to tomcat config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new maven webproject and migrated all the files incrementally to the new project.

After that it works without log4j errors!

Answer (score 5):

It's a log4j 1.2.15 [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43867) with Tomcat. Update to version 1.2.17 or change to log4j 2 and the error message will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

edit the catalina properties

CATALINA_OPTS=-Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. Setting the system property

```
-Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
```

solved the symptom.

However, there's probably an underlying error. In my case there was a `ClassNotFoundException`. Check your tomcat logs.

For explanations see this [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43867#c10), which says it happens during shutdown, but it seems to be the same bug. Also try [this page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html).